# pubspec.yaml file is not showing in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Where is my `pubspec.yaml` in Android Studio?

[image: Android Studio]

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **Android** then select **Project**, that's it. You'll find the `pubspec.yaml` file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are currently in Android directory.

You have to click on the Android with Icon on Top right and select Project there.

See below screen-print for clarity.

[image: Android Studio]